# docker --insecure-registry flag not working as expected

Tags: docker

The instructions for private registries with self signed certs state when logging in:

> FATA[0005] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with
>   error: Get https://registry:8443/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority. If this private registry supports only HTTP or
>   HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry
>   registry:8443` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you
>   have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag;
>   simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/registry:8443/ca.crt

I tried that but got another error about the IP not being in the subject. So I fixed that error and now get:

> FATA[0006] Error response from daemon: Server Error: Post
>   https://registry:8443/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown
>   authority

Where registry is the IP of the registry.

I then placed "--insecure-registry registry:8443"  in /etc/default/docker and restarted the daemon

I've verified it's taken the setting.

> root      6865     1  0 12:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker -d
>   --insecure-registry registry:8443

But docker login still produces this error:

> FATA[0006] Error response from daemon: Server Error: Post
>   https://registry:8443/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown
>   authority

Does insecure-registry work differently than I thought and how do I get around it?

And yes, I need HTTPS.  It's a private registry but on a public IP.  Is the only way forward to create a proper DNS entry with a real cert?

Comment: +1 for this question. Currently I don't need HTTPS (and `--insecure-registry` works well), but I will have to enable this feature at an early date.

Comment: And in the end I couldn't solve it as described.  Instead, I added a DNS entry and a real cert and that fixed it for me.  I'd still like to know how you deploy self signed though.

Comment: if this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04) won't help me, I guess I'll have to deploy my own Certificate Authority and configure my environment to trust them (probably will use FreeIPA for that purpose)

Answer (score 9):

## Recommended Way Docker 17.xx +

There are a number of ways to configure the daemon flags and environment variables for your Docker daemon. The [recommended way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file) is to use the platform-independent `daemon.json` file, which is located in `/etc/docker/` on Linux by default.

So, for configuring insecure registries, do the following:

1. Set the following flag in the `daemon.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "insecure-registries": ["registry:8443"]
   }
   ```
2. Restart Docker

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

That's it!

Answer (score 6):

YES! I've found the problem!

You need to fix `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service`. Currently it doesn't take $OPTIONS into consideration when starting docker. So mine now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
#The line below was missing $OPTIONS at the end!!!
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $OPTIONS
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that do the usual:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

and everything works now.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I would also like to add that I needed to set an http connector (even though I have no proxy) and expose that port on the docker container, which is also a pita.

Answer (score 1):

*Since I already upvoted this issue months ago, because I had the same problem, and now - hopefully - having a solution for it, I'd like the share with you the following paragraph I wrote for our private wiki...*

#### Setup Private registries (with self-signed certificates)

In order to `docker login` to a private registry you have to distribute the certificate generated above to the Docker-nodes.

Download `*.example.com` wildcard cert and the intermediate cert for self-signed certs from haxx.se and restart the Docker daemon.

```
curl -k https://git.example.com/herzog/pub/raw/master/ssh/example.com.crt > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/registry.example.com-ca.crt
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem
sudo update-ca-certificates
sudo service docker restart
```

Output example for CA update

```
root@test1:~# sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 2 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

Login to the private registry

```
docker login --username registry --email reg@example.com https://registry.example.com/v1
```

> Notice! The registry host specified with https://.../v1 should work for `docker` and `docker-compose`

and pull an image

```
docker pull registry.example.com/namespace/image:1.0.0
```

Comment: So looks like the solution is to place your client cert on the system and register it with update-ca-certificates.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: "Could not resolve host: git.example.com"

Answer (score 0):

The best and also most platform-independent way is to use the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` [configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/daemon-configuration-file).

Behold:

```
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<DOCKERCONFIG
{
  "insecure-registries": ["registry:8443"]
}
DOCKERCONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution was:

1. Modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as is mention before
2. Modify permissions to:
   `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with

   `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: this is not good idea to set RWX to all users.