# Docker insecure-registries only showing in sudo docker info

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-registry

some help would be appreciated.

I run a server and am running a docker-registry that I'm trying to push/pull to from my local device. My local device is configured as per:

1. `sudo vim /etc/hosts` of your local device and add a new entry:

   ```
   # Manually added for server Docker registry
   <server_ip>     nuc
   ```
2. `ping nuc` to ensure connection.
3. `sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json`

   ```bash
   {
       "insecure-registries": ["nuc:5000"]
   }
   ```
4. Edit `sudo vim /etc/default/docker`

   ```bash
   {
       # Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
       DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=nuc:5000"
   }
   ```

The issue I get is that when running `docker info` the specified `insecure-registry` isn't listed, however, when I run `sudo docker info` it is listed. Please note that my current `$USER` is part of the `docker` group and I can run docker commands without needing to use `sudo` (the following was followed: [Docker post-install steps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)).

Note I got inspiration from StackOverflow at:

- [Add Insecure Registry to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker)
- [Add Insecure Registry to Docker in ubuntu [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116766/add-insecure-registry-to-docker-in-ubuntu)
- [Insecure Docker registry and self-signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727327/insecure-docker-registry-and-self-signed-certificates)
- [docker --insecure-registry flag not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402864/docker-insecure-registry-flag-not-working-as-expected)

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Additional info**

- `docker context ls`

  ```bash
  NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
  default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                          
  desktop-linux *     moby                Docker Desktop                            unix:///home/ben/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
  ```
- `sudo docker context ls`

  ```bash
  NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
  default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  ```
- `printenv DOCKER_HOST` and `echo $DOCKER_HOST` returned with nothing
- `sudo printenv DOCKER_HOST` and `sudo echo $DOCKER_HOST` returned with nothing

Comment: Please show the output of `docker context ls` and `sudo docker context ls` along with `printenv DOCKER_HOST` and `sudo printenv DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: @BMitch thanks, I've added an `EDIT: Additional info` section - please note that the `DOCKER_HOST` doesn't seem to have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `docker context` output, it appears that you have two separate docker engines. One is installed directly on the host, running as root, and listening on `/var/run/docker.sock`. The other engine is running inside of a VM with Docker Desktop.

The [documentation for Desktop on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/linux/) specifies their own config file location at `~/.docker/desktop/settings.json`, and there should also be a UI for updating its insecure-registries setting.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch appreciate it, that solved my issue. I'm, however, curious what would be considered the correct vanilla install? Surely there should only be one `docker engine` installed? That being `root` and used by the user signed in by means of adding them to the `docker` group?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear from this how you installed docker twice.

Comment: If you're interested I install `docker` as part of my `Ansible` script when I setup my device as can be found here: [Ansible_Ubuntu_Dev_Config](https://github.com/BenWolfaardt/Ansible_Ubuntu_Dev_Config/blob/main/roles/docker/tasks/main.yml)